# Configuring port for django development environment, so the site is available from outside

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, port

I am experimenting with django and I throw the code on my server like explained in the first chapters of the django book 2.0.

I have apache running on this server, too (port 80). If I stop apache I can start my django site by calling

```
sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

If I access it from another machine by

```
http://myservername:80
```

it works fine. Now, apache is running an important page, and I don't want to let apache stoped. How do I make mysite available on another port?

Edit: I'll try to explain more:

When apache runs, typing into the adressfield of my browser, shows me the "important wepage".

Starting my django test project with

```
sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:anotherport
```

and accessing trying to acces it by

```
http://ipadressofserver:anotherport
```

does not work.

If apache is tuned off, and I start my django project by

```
sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

I can access it by

```
http://myservername
http://myservername:80 (the browser changes this to http://myservername/
http://myserverIP and http://myservrIP:80 (The latter resolves in the former).
```

I am not experienced in Serveradministration so please ask me, if there is something specific I can tell you, to help me solve the problem, please ask me, and I'll provide the information - if possible.

Comment: one thing to note is that runserver is only for the django development server and should not be used in conjunction with apache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify a different port when starting the dev server:

```
$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and connect to the site via:

```
 http://myserverip:8000
```

Comment: I tryed that already, but it does not solve my problem. I added some (hopefully useful) information to my question.

Comment: This answer is all that is required. If it's still not working for you, you must have the port blocked in your firewall (either on the server, a separate firewall appliance, or your router).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to configure your router appropriately to point to any port. This question should more directly relate to how do you expose a specific port to be browsed. Any information you could provide about your router would be more helpful to address this.